# Random iteration for list

Tags: python-3.x

This is what I am trying to accomplish, however, I have run into an issue where it is printing my data incorrectly.

In the main function:
create an empty list.
use a for loop to add 12 random integers, all ranging from 50 to 100, to the list.
use second for loop to iterate over the list and display all elements on one line separated by a single space.
display the 4th element, the element at index 9, and the smallest element.
call the change_list function with your list as its sole argument.

Here's the code I used:

```
import random
def main():
    list1 = []
    for count in range (12):
        number = random.randint(50,101)
        list1.append(number)
    for num in number:
        print(num)

        
main()
```

Im not sure how to get it to print each number that was generated individually for the second loop.

Comment: The code that you wrote does exactly what it is meant to do. re-read your assigment, especially the "second for loop" thing. I'm sure you will succeed at doing your homework

Comment: You're printing your list every time you're adding the random number -- so that's why there's 12 rows of printout.

Comment: ya that makes sense.. its the obvious stuff that gets me sometimes ;-;